# angular 2 webpack 2 lazy load module throwing template parse error

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, webpack-2

im using webpack 2.2.0 . my appmodule loads properly and also on route the chunk is downloaded but it throws template parse error

"Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property"

if im trying to load commonmodule in dynamic module it throws duplicate error

Dynamic route (app-routing):

```
  {
    path: "reports/:id",
    loadChildren: () => {
        return System.import('./reports/tabularReportsFachade/tabularReportsFachade.module').then((comp: any) => {
            debugger
            return comp.TabularReportsFachadeModule;
        });
    }
```

child route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    component: TabularReportsFachadeComponent,pathMatch: 'full'
}
];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Child module:

```
 @NgModule({
imports: [ routing, FormsModule],
exports: [MyComponents],
declarations: [MyComponents],
bootstrap: [TabularReportsFachadeComponent],

})
 export class TabularReportsFachadeModule {

static routing = routing;
}
```

webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    'polyfills': './Scripts/polyfills',
    "vendor": "./Scripts/vendor",
    "main": "./Scripts/main"
},
output: {
    filename: "./Scripts/[name].bundle.js",
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".html"]
},
devtool: 'sourcemap',
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
          test: /.ts$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader'
      },
      {
          test: /.css$/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      }
    ]
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `BrowserModule` too.

Import BrowserModule in the root module and CommonModule in other modules where you want to use common directives.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  ...
})
class AppModule {}
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  // Now MyComponent has access to ngIf
  declarations: [MyComponent]
  ...
})
class OtherModule {}
```

BrowserModule exports CommonModule, this way it's not necessary to import CommonModule directly in the root module.

Answer (score 1):

Ng module add [CommonModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CommonModule-class.html) to use some common directives:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ routing, FormsModule, CommonModule ],
  exports: [MyComponents],
  declarations: [MyComponents],
  bootstrap: [TabularReportsFachadeComponent],

})
export class TabularReportsFachadeModule {

  static routing = routing;
}
```

Comment: as i'm importing commonModule inside my appmodul already, importing here again gives me duplicate module error

Comment: i don't think so, maybe you already imports BrowserModule in AppModule, then you import CommonModule also. note that, BrowserModule include CommonModule. remove CommonModule if you already have BrowserModule. but in other Module, if you wanna using directive like ngIf, NgFor, etc you need import CommonModule or BrowserModule, not both of them.